# create dropdown with multiple selection in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement a dropdown similar to the one on Booking.com in terms of functionality (I attach a screenshot), but I am encountering some issues and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Do you have any suggestions?
[image]

HTML

```
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                <input type="text" id="droptxt" class="list" readonly placeholder="Number of guests">
                                <div id="content" class="content">
                                    <div class="list">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="rooms" class="list" value="Choose how many rooms" />
                                        <label for="Choose how many rooms" class="list">Choose how many rooms </label>
                                        <input type="hidden" class="list quantity" min="1" value="1" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="list">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="adults" class="list" value="Choose the number of adults" />
                                        <label for="Choose the number of adults" class="list">Choose the number of adults </label>
                                        <input type="hidden" class="list quantity" min="1" value="1" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="list">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="children" class="list" value="Choose the number of children" />
                                        <label for="Choose the number of children" class="list">Choose the number of children </label>
                                        <input type="hidden" class="list quantity" min="1" value="1" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

JavaScript

```
const txt = document.getElementById('droptxt');
console.log(txt);
const content = document.getElementById('content');
console.log(content);
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.list input[type="checkbox"]');
const quantity = document.querySelectorAll('.list input[type="number"]');

txt.addEventListener('click', function() {
    content.classList.toggle('show');
});

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.list')) {
        if (content.classList.contains('show')) content.classList.remove('show');
    }
};

checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox, index) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
        quantity[index].type = (checkbox.checked) ? 'number' : 'hidden';
        calc();
    });
});

quantity.forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener('input', calc);
});

function calc() {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            arr.push(quantity[i].value + ' x ' + checkboxes[i].value);
        }
    }

    txt.value = arr.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Please describe your issues, as well as the expected result.

Comment: I want it to behave the same way as the one highlighted in the screenshot on booking.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const quantity = document.querySelectorAll('.list input[type="number"]');
```

in this line you are selecting input[type="number"] but in your html there is no input which type is number. use this

```
 const quantity = document.querySelectorAll('.list input[type="hidden"]');
```

it will solve your problem